# bind a tempory variable to a non const reference compile on visual

Tags: c++, rvalue

```
#include<iostream>

struct Foo
{

};

void func(Foo& f)
{
    std::cout << "foo" ;
}

int main()
{ 
    func(Foo());//ok compile
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 1;
}
```

the standard doesn't say this king of thing is not legal ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: This is a microsoft extension. Extensions can be disabled by specifying the `/Za` compiler switch.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be legal. But some older version of Visual C++ (for instance VC6) allow it, afaik.

Comment: All versions allow it. It's non-standard extension.